# Find the local linearization of f(x) near 0 and use this to approximate the value of a.

Tags: calculus

$$ f(x) = (1+x)^\frac35, a= (1.2)^\frac35 $$

I got the linear approximation equation of $$1+ \frac35 x$$
What do I do with the value of a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$ f(x) = (1+x)^\frac35 \approx 1+\frac35x$$, then $f(a)=f(1.2)=f(1+0.2)\approx1+\frac35\times 0.2=1.12$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: $f(x)=a$ when $x=\cdots\,$.

Find $f(x)$ approximately by using this $x$ value in the linear approximation.

Comment: So x is 0 and I should plug the given value of A in?

Comment: If $x=0$ then $f(x)=(1+0)^{3/5}=1$ which is not equal to $a$.  Can you solve $(1+x)^{3/5}=(1.2)^{3/5}$?

Comment: Yep. 1.1156 thereabout.

Comment: If $(1+x)^{3/5}=(1.2)^{3/5}$ then $1+x=1.2$ so $x=0.2$.